# How to remove Fedora (and all its programmes), keep its users and install Ubuntu instead?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, migration

So my old fedora 28 has a core I do not like, and an old version I do not enjoy. Its update is not possible due to tons of errors. So how to remove Fedora and its core (and all its programmes), keep its users and install Ubuntu instead?

Answer (score 1):

If your `/home` is on a separate partition (or logical volume which is default with Fedora) you can simply install Ubuntu and [reuse the `/home` for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder). It will remove the user accounts, so you'll need to create the user again but the data and user configuration which is saved in the `/home` directory will be reused.

If you don't have a separate `/home` partition/volume you'll need to backup your data (which I recommend doing even if you have separate `/home`) and do a fresh "full" installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: Are there any automated  user restoration scripts?